# How to identify EPSG of any shapefile

Tags: postgis, geoserver, shapefile, postgresql

I have a shapefile, imported in PostgreSQL using PostGIS when this shapefile is published in GeoServer it didn't show any layer.

I had used EPSG:4326..

Comment: 'SELECT ST_asEWKT(geom) from TABLE something' and if values are -90..90 and -180...180 its probably 4326. You can also try -1 or 0

Answer (score 3):

The shapefile should have a .prj file which contains the CRS information. It does not  necessarily contain the EPSG code itself, but you can open the file with any text editor, and insert the content in your question.

[spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/) is an online database with most known coordinate refrence systems.